# Rails - link_to a user#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In rails how do I do a link_to a user show page of the current user. Basically i want a link that go to a account page.

I tried it but i get this.

> Routing Error  No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}

**Routes.rb**

```
LootApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "password_resets/new"
  get "sessions/new"
  get "static_pages/home"
  get "static_pages/help"

  resources :sessions
  resources :password_resets
  resources :email_activations

  resources :users do
    collection do 
      get :accept_invitation
    end 
  end

  root to: 'static_pages#home'
  match "sign_up",      to: "users#new"
  match '/help',        to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/log_in',      to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/log_out',     to: 'sessions#destroy'
```

**Application.html.haml**

```
      - if current_user 
        = link_to "log out", log_out_path
        - if current_user.admin?
          # your admin
        - else
          = link_to "My account", user_path
      - else
        = link_to "log in", log_in_path
```

**Users controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :admin_and_user, only: [:destory, :edit, :show]

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id]) 
  end
```

**rake routes**

```
              users GET    /users(.:format)                      users#index
                    POST   /users(.:format)                      users#create
           new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                  users#new
          edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)             users#edit
               user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                  users#show
                    PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                  users#update
                    DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                  users#destroy
```

Comment: i tried = link_to "My account", user_path(params[:id])

Answer (score 11, accepted):

just

```
<%= link_to current_user.name, current_user%>
```

Answer (score 5):

The current answer is the best solution, but just to elaborate: The problem that was causing an error in your code was that you needed to specify which user the link should link to. So instead of just `user_path` should you do like this:

```
= link_to "My account", user_path(current_user)
```

A shortcut for this is (as shown in the current answer by @Muntasim)

```
= link_to "My account", current_user
```

Comment: Lovely to see somebody offering an explanation with their answer. Cheers @jokklan.

Comment: `user_path(current_user)` is what I was looking for. Is there any reason there is no `current_user_path`?

Comment: @Nemo because the model is called "User" not "CurrentUser". However you can create it yourself: `resources :users, as: :current_users`
You can read more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-named-helpers